# Tool to convert SQL syntax to ActiveRecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, syntax, converters

There are many questions to help converting specific SQL query to ActiveRecord query.

Are there some assistance/guidance [online] tools to make the conversion automatically?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

here is the tool you are looking: http://www.scuttle.io/

Comment: why this application want to read all our public and private repositories?

Comment: My 5 line hard coded join statements were converted to 20 lines of Rails Models and Chain Functions hahahha